# 'npm run build' does not work properly with vue.js 3 and vue-router 4

Tags: docker, vue.js, vue-router, httpserver

I have created a vue.js 3 project and when I run `npm run serve`, all paths of my vie-router work.

However, when I try 'npm run build' and use either Nginx or http-serve to serve the build folder, only '/' path works and other paths are not found.

Here is the Dockerfile I use:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
CMD ["http-server", "build", "--port", "80"]
```

Then I run the following docker commands:

```
docker buildx build -t my-app:latest . --load
docker run -p 8080:80 my-app:latest
```

When I hit 'localhost:8080/', I get the page.
However, when I go to 'localhost:8080/login' for example, I receive an Error (404): Not found.

I have tried adding `publicPath: ""` to vue.config.js module.exports but without success.

Could you please help?

Comment: Sounds like a nginx config problem to me. Maybe this will help you https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx

Comment: If you `docker run --rm my-app ls`, does the image contain the `index.html` file?  A `login/index.html` page or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot julian and David Maze for your help. Following your recommendations, I was able to solve the problem.

This problem is known to the Vue.js community as documented here https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#routing-with-history-pushstate

In order to solve that, you need a custom configuration for your server setup (Nginx ...).

In my case, I use Nginx, so I followed this link https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx to create the correct docker image.

It worked just fine!